# Jest "jest.mock(...) does not overwrite the original file

Tags: mocking, jestjs

So I set up my mocks exactly like in the documentation (despite me needing require and the docs using import, but that should not be the problem afaik)

```
jest.mock('common-bon/lib/utils/events/EventDomains');
const EventDomains = require('common-bon/lib/utils/events/EventDomains');
...
beforeAll(()=>{

EventDomains.mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
        app: 'Placeholder'
    };
  });
});
```

This is exactly how they do it  here:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks

But it doesnt work.
The test suite terminate with

> TypeError: EventDomains.mockImplementation is not a function

Which afaik means that the mocking simply didn't work.

*Context as to what I need the mock for:*
*in the source Code a Function I call ends with:

```
    handler.fireEvent(domain.app);
```

where "domain" is  what I want to mock:

```
const domain = EventDomains;
const EventDomains = require('common').utils.getEventDomains();
```

*the complex "path" works out to being what I use in jest.mock(...), which works for other mocks where I don't need to change mockImplementation*

Edit: I know for a fact that it is the "jest.mock(...)" part that is not working, because when I added the function "mockImplementation" to the ORIGINAL file, it worked perfectly fine.
[mind you that jest.mock as well as the require which came before the .mockImplementation used the exact same path.
The require is at the top of the test file and the .mockImplementation is in a "beforeAll) [though having it directly below the require does not make a difference]

Answer (score 0):

**Just skip the ".mockImplementation" part!**

My solution is in the test file:

```
    beforeAll(()=>{
    EventDomains.app = 'placeholder'    
    });
```

That's it.
No complex ".mockImplementation" etc. required.